# React checkedLink how to access value on change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React to write a simple component for a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" checkedLink={this.linkState('checkedValue')} />
```

I cannot however figure out what code gets triggered on change of the checkbox value.  Am I supposed to retrieve the value onFocus or is there a better convention for retrieving the value after a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab the state of your checkbox by adding an `onChange` handler something like this:

```
function handleChange (event) {
  console.log(event.target.checked)
}

<input onChange={handleChange} type='checkbox' />
```

Comment: While I understand you want to use `checkedLink`, maybe the "default" solution could be a good fit for you use-case

Comment: Hi Aperçu thanks for the quick response.  I  thought about using this earlier but i'm a little unclear about what the usefulness is of the checkedLink functionality then is.  Im still new to React but I was really hoping I was just missing something about the way it worked and it called a method I could implement to save the change.

Comment: You could see in the [two way binding docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) that "If you're new to the framework, note that ReactLink is not needed for most applications and should be used cautiously", but you can still use it if you really want to. I think you miss the `mixin` for it to work, all you need to know about it is in this doc ;)